# Why do I not get any content with python requests get, but still a 200 response?

Tags: python, django, python-requests

I'm doing a `requests.get(url='url', verify=False),` from my django application hosted on an Ubuntu server from AWS, to a url that has a Django Rest Framework. There are no permissions or authentication on the DRF, because I'm the one that made it. I've added headers such as

`headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}`, but wasn't able to get any content.

BUT when I do run `./manage.py shell` and run the exact same command, I get the output that I need!

EDIT 1:
So I've started using `subprocess.get_output("curl <url> --insecure", shell=True)` and it works, but I know this is not a very "nice" way to do things.

Comment: How did you try to see the content? `req = requests.get(url='url', verify=False)` and then `print(req.json())` what do you see?

Comment: @roganjosh I actually don't get anything. If I add a `logger.error(req.json())`, it doesn't log. From what I can see from my debugger, it hangs right at `requests.get()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know what the problem was.
My application when it was being deployed was single threaded, not multithreaded.
I changed my worker number and that fixed everything.